# Protactinium-234 half-life

Tags: isotope

This is going to seem like a rather daft question, but what is the definitive half-live for protactinium-234 (<sup>234</sup>Pa)?  I'm seeing lots of different answers in various academic papers etc.

For instance, in Bonotto & Andrews (2000) the half-life of protactinium-234 (<sup>234</sup>Pa) is given as 1.18 minutes, but in Edwards et al. (2003) they report the <sup>234</sup>Pa half-life as 6.67 hours.  So which one is it?

Bonotto, D.M. & Andrews, J.N. The transfer of uranium isotopes <sup>234</sup>U and <sup>238</sup>U to the waters interacting with carbonates from Mendip Hills area (England). *Applied Radiation and Isotopes*. 52, 965-983. 2000.  DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0969-8043(99)00151-7

Edwards, R.L., Gallup, C.D. & C Uranium-series Dating of Marine and Lacustrine Carbonates.  *Reviews in Mineralogy & Geochemistry*. 52, 363-406 . 2003. URL: http://www.minsocam.org/msa/rim/Rim52.html

Answer (score 2):

> So which one is it?

Both! Proactinium-234 exhibits **[nuclear isomerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer)**. The metastable form $\ce{^{234m}Pa}$ has a half-life time in the range of 1 min, whereas $\ce{^{234}Pa}$ shows a half-life time around 6 hrs.

Comment: In fact, if you check out the Wikipedia article on [nuclear isomers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer), the $\ce{^{234}Pa}/ \ce{^{234m}Pa}$ pair is the oldest known example of nuclear isomerism.

Comment: Okay.  So the half-life length depends on the state of the nuclear spin.  With 234Pa having a 4+ state and 234mPa having a 0- state.  So out of the two, which half-life is more common?  Is it similar to branched decay, in that one pathway, in this case half-life rather than decay mode, is more common than the other?